# .htaccess link ProxyPass

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

From the link https://assets.example.org/mydocument.pdf I need change for https://example.org/assets/mydocument.pdf the link that works in my server.
I'm using in my .htaccess:

ProxyPass        "/assets/" "https://assets.example.org/"
ProxyPassReverse "/assets/" "https://assets.example.org/"

Substitute "s|https://assets.example.org/|https://example.com/assets/|i"

but doesn't work

I'm trying that https://assets.example.org/mydocument.pdf works

Comment: Use a redirect and not ProxyPass. Something like `RewriteRule ^mydocument.pdf$ https://example.org/assets/mydocument.pdf [L,R=302]` https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html